# Sum if returns 0 when criteria has an operator referring to a cell and works if cell value is entered manually

Tags: excel

I am using `sum` if function and if the operator in the criteria refers to a cell it returns zero and if the cell value is entered manually inside the criteria it works just fine

```
=SUMIF($AC$9:$AC$25,">=AB9",$AE$9:$AE$25)
```

doesn't work and works if like this

```
=SUMIF($AC$9:$AC$25,">=15.25",$AE$9:$AE$25)
```

Comment: Did you try `$AB$9`?

Comment: tried and returns zero as well, it doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

As shown in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b, you need to "build" the criteria expression; in your case, replace

```
">=AB9"
```

with

```
">=" & AB9
```

Comment: ">=" & AB9 worked also just fine, thanks so much dude :)

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out finally...we can't use operators like > or < to refer to a cell inside the sum if criteria, but we can trick excel to do it....we can use concatenate to add > or < to the cell value and in the sum if criteria we can refer directly to the new concatenated cell like this :))

=CONCATENATE(">=",AO3,"") which returns >=15.25 in a new cell which is AO3
we then refer to it directly like this
=SUMIF($AC$9:$AC$25,AO3,$AE$9:$AE$25)

Cheers :)))